# How to convert a sound file from wav to ulaw?

Tags: audio

I need a utility to convert from wav to ulaw for my IVR. What third-party software can I use?

Answer (score 3):

This is the opposite of what you are trying to do, but I thought it could be helpful to someone. Here is an exmple method that will convert an 8-bit uLaw encoded binary file into a 16-bit WAV file using built-in Java methods.

```java
public static void convertULawFileToWav(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (!file.exists())
        return;
    try {
        long fileSize = file.length();
        int frameSize = 160;
        long numFrames = fileSize / frameSize;
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(Encoding.ULAW, 8000, 8, 1, frameSize, 50, true);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), audioFormat, numFrames);
        AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, Type.WAVE, new File("C:\\file.wav"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```